# GitHub GraphQL fetch repositories that are not archived

Tags: graphql, github-api, github-graphql

Is there a way to fetch only the repos that are not archived?

```
{
  user(login: "SrikanthBandaru") {
    id
    email
    isHireable
    name
    repositories(first: 100) { # fetch only the repos that are not archived
      edges {
        node {
          name
          isArchived
          shortDescriptionHTML
          description
          descriptionHTML
          repositoryTopics(first: 10) {
            edges {
              node {
                topic {
                  name
                }
              }
            }
          }
          homepageUrl
          url
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a search query in addition to user query with the [archived search parameter](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-for-repositories/#search-based-on-whether-a-repository-is-archived). Also use `fork:true` to include forks:

```graphql
{
  user: user(login: "simon04") {
    id
    email
    isHireable
    name
  }
  repos: search(query: "user:simon04 fork:true archived:false", type: REPOSITORY, first: 100) {
    repositoryCount
    edges {
      node {
        ... on Repository {
          nameWithOwner
          name
          isArchived
          shortDescriptionHTML
          description
          descriptionHTML
          repositoryTopics(first: 10) {
            edges {
              node {
                topic {
                  name
                }
              }
            }
          }
          homepageUrl
          url
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20user%3A%20user(login%3A%20%22simon04%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%0A%20%20%20%20email%0A%20%20%20%20isHireable%0A%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20repos%3A%20search(query%3A%20%22user%3Asimon04%20fork%3Atrue%20archived%3Afalse%22%2C%20type%3A%20REPOSITORY%2C%20first%3A%20100)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20repositoryCount%0A%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Repository%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20nameWithOwner%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20isArchived%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shortDescriptionHTML%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20description%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20descriptionHTML%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20repositoryTopics(first%3A%2010)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20topic%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20homepageUrl%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20url%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

Comment: ahh..!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can run the query below to filter out archived repository in the Github org; I used the pageInfo request to get the endcursor for paginating into the next page.

```html
query {
  organization(login: "orgname") {
    repositories(isArchived:false, first: 100) {  # adjust this value based on your needs
      edges {
        node {
          name
          vulnerabilityAlerts(first: 100) {  # adjust this value based on your needs
            edges {
              node {
                id
                securityVulnerability {
                  package {
                    name
                    ecosystem
                  }
                  severity
                  updatedAt
                }
                vulnerableRequirements
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      pageInfo {
        endCursor
        hasNextPage
      } 
    }
  }
}
```